# Hibernate Search: Elasticsearch and Lucene yield different search results

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to implement a quite basic search functionality for my REST backend using Spring Data Rest and Hibernate Search. I would like to allow users to execute arbitrary queries by passing query strings to a search function. In order to be able to easier run the backend locally and to avoid having to spin up Elasticsearch to run tests, I would like to be able to work with a local index in these situations.

My problem is that the following code, does not yield equal results using local index compared to Elasticsearch. I am trying to limit the following code to what I believe is relevant.

The entity:

```
@Indexed(index = "MyEntity")
@AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class ),
    filters = {
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class,
        params = {
          @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "2"),
          @Parameter(name = "maxGramSize", value = "3") } )
    }
)
public class MyEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "ngram"))
    private String name;

    @Field(analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    @FieldBridge(impl = StringCollectionFieldBridge.class)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();

}
```

application.yml for local index:

```
spring: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: false
```

application.yml for Elasticsearch:

```
spring: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          default:
            indexmanager: elasticsearch
            elasticsearch:
              host: 127.0.0.1:9200
              required_index_status: yellow
```

Search endpoint:

```
private static String[] FIELDS = { "name", "tags" };

@Override
public List<MyEntity> querySearch(String queryString) throws ParseException {
    QueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(FIELDS, new SimpleAnalyzer());
    queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = 
            fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, MyEntity.class);

    return persistenceQuery.getResultList();
}
```

I create a instance of MyEntity with the following values:

```
$ curl 'localhost:8086/myentities'
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "myentities" : [ {
      "name" : "Test Entity",
      "tags" : [ "bar", "foobar", "foo" ],
      "_links" : {
        ...
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

The following queries work (return that entity) using Elasticsearch:

- name:Test
- name:Entity
- tags:bar

Using a local index, I get the result for "tags:bar: but the queries on the name field return not results. Any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that the Elasticsearch mapping is properly created by Hibernate Search. By default, Hiberante Search will only create a mapping if it is missing.

If you launched your application once, then changed the mapping, and launched the application again, it is possible that the `name` field does not have the correct in Elasticsearch.

In development mode, try this:

```
spring: 
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          default:
            indexmanager: elasticsearch
            elasticsearch:
              host: 127.0.0.1:9200
              required_index_status: yellow
              index_schema_management_strategy: drop-and-create-and-drop
```

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-schema-management-strategy

Note that documents being successfully indexed is unfortunately not an indication that your mapping is correct: Elasticsearch even creates fields dynamically when you try to index unknown fields trying to guess their type (generally wrong, in the case of text fields...). You can use the `validate` index management strategy to be really sure that, on bootstrap, the Elasticsearch mapping is in sync with Hibernate Search.

Comment: Followijg up on your hint about synchronization between the index and database, I found out, that the results actually are the same: The name queries return nothing, the tag query works in both. I suspect the SimpleAnalyzer to be the cause of this, abut that's a different problem.